Как на python создать свой почтовый сервер?
Хочу создать почтовый сервер на python. Когда я гуглил, то находил только inbox.py у которого не нашел нормальной документации. Можете посоветовать либо другую библиотеку, либо документацию по inbox?
Домен и хостинг у меня есть

Но зачем, если существуют десятки готовых и проверенных временем почтовых серверов?

Вопрос скорее не в практической пользе, а в опыте и обучении

Изучайте документацию на протокол SMTP и реализуйте его.

@CrazyElf, Я пытаюсь найти готовое решение в виде библиотеки, но если не смогу, то прислушаюсь к вашему совету

Стоп, а вообще-то в питоне есть стандартный модуль smtpd: https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/smtpd.html, вот исходник: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/smtpd.py

@CrazyElf, огромное спасибо, если вы оформите это как ответ, то я отмечу его как правильный

В стандартных библиотеках Питона есть много чего, в том числе и SMTP сервер в виде модуля smtpd, а в его документации есть и ссылка на его питоновский исходник smtpd.py.
Хотя вообще-то этот модуль устарел и там же рекомендуется использовать современный асинхронный вариант aiosmtpd. Его исходники можно найти здесь, там уже далеко не один файл.
